# Mongoose geolocation query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have documents with the following format in a bundle of mongdb data:

```
{
    "_id": "5839f170ca31803284785ef3",
    "name": "Alex",
    "coordinates": {
        "type": "point",
        "coordinates": [
            -23.073889,
            -44.96
        ]
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I would like to execute a query where I enter the latitude and longitude of the center point and the size of the radius and the answer is all the users that are within that radius.

I'm starting with mongoose and have no idea how to do this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.find({
  'coordinates.coordinates': {
    $geoWithin: {
      $center: [[<x>, <y>], radius]
    },
  },
});
```

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/center/